# how to find out offending user using tty information

Tags: linux, command

I have an script called wow.sh on a shared machine.

'ps -ef | grep wow' shows multiple runs of the same script.

How can I use the tty information to find the offending users ip?

Answer (score 0):

You can try "last", which will show you last logins.  So if you narrowed it down to a user, you can run `last username` and the 3rd column is their login origin.

Answer (score 0):

In the most basic sense, you need to track down who ran it and where they logged in from:

```
ps axo command,user,lstart | grep [w]ow
```

The 2nd field gives you the user. If this is obvious (i.e. not 'root' or some shared username) then you can use 'last' as Alex mentions:

```
ps axo user,command,lstart | grep [w]ow | cut -f1 -d' ' | xargs last -n 1000 -iF
```

Just match up their date from the first command (the 'lstart' last column) with the login/logout reported by last.

Comment: All the users login using a common user. The only thing to differentiate between them is the tty information. I want to find out the ip using the tty information.

Answer (score 0):

If the offending party will still be logged in (i.e. they're not `disown`-ing scripts or similar) then `who` will give you the IP and tty of the logged-in users.